# How do I use gstreamer to provide musiconhold to asterisk

Tags: gstreamer, asterisk, sip, rtsp

I am trying to use gstreamer to capture an rtsp stream and make it available as musiconhold within asterisk which requires 8000Hz wav format.

Answer (score 0):

User the following command to send

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc protocols=tcp location=rtsp://fqdn-example.com/stream uridecodebin0::source::latency=1000 ! decodebin ! deinterleave ! audioresample quality=10 ! audio/x-raw,rate=8000 ! udpsink host=1.2.3.4 port=1234
```

then in the musiconhold.conf

```
[moh]
mode=custom
application=/usr/local/bin/socat -u udp4-recv:1234 -
```

you may need to install the socat command. You can put the whole gst command in the application= but I like being able to control the stream from a screen session. If you do you will need to append

```
! filesink location=/dev/stdout
```

instead of the ! udpsink...